# How to display items according to categories from already loaded list of all models in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have loaded a list of images and their details from API into a automatic expand gridview.Below is code on how I loaded the details from API into gridview.I have a hamburger menu on my left side.It has category view.For example if I have many dynamic categories ,how will I show in the Gridview from already loaded images and details.

```
List<int> assetiid = new List<int>();
List<string> productname = new List<string>();
List<string> productcatogery = new List<string>();
List<string> productcatogeryid = new List<string>();
List<string> productdesc = new List<string>();
List<int> assetpriceurl = new List<int>();
List<string> assetimageurl = new List<string>();
List<string> assetimageurl1 = new List<string>();
List<string> assetimageurl2 = new List<string>();
List<string> assetimageurl3 = new List<string>();


List<string> assetmodelurl = new List<string>();


string JSONDataString;


public static PopulateGrid Instancepop;

public void Awake()
{
    Instancepop = this;
}


// Use this for initialization
public void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetData());

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{


}

IEnumerator GetData()
{

    string URL = "http://test.com/test/api/products";//fake api
    WWW readjson = new WWW(URL);
    yield return readjson;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(readjson.error))
    {

        JSONDataString = readjson.text;
    }

    JSONNode JNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(JSONDataString);

    for (int i = 0; i < JNode.Count; i++)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Image URLS before = " + JNode[i]["product_images"][0]);
        assetiid.Add(JNode[i]["id"]);
        productname.Add(JNode[i]["product_name"]);
        productcatogery.Add(JNode[i]["product_category"]);
        productcatogeryid.Add(JNode[i]["product_category_id"]);
        productdesc.Add(JNode[i]["product_description"]);
        assetpriceurl.Add(JNode[i]["product_price"]);

        assetimageurl.Add(JNode[i]["product_images"][0]);
        assetimageurl1.Add(JNode[i]["product_images"][1]);
        assetimageurl2.Add(JNode[i]["product_images"][2]);
        assetimageurl3.Add(JNode[i]["product_images"][3]);

        assetmodelurl.Add(JNode[i]["product_model"]);


        Debug.Log("Image URLS = "+assetimageurl[i] );


    }

    StartCoroutine(FillData());


}

IEnumerator FillData()
{
    //for (int i = 0; i < assetimageurl.Count; i++)
    for (int i = 0; i < assetimageurl.Count; i++)
    {
        Texture2D tex;
        tex = new Texture2D(150, 150, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);


        WWW imgurllinks = new WWW(assetimageurl[i]);
        yield return imgurllinks;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgurllinks.error))
        {
            yield return null;

        }

        imgurllinks.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
        rimg.texture = tex;

        //RawImage newItem = Instantiate(rimg) as RawImage;
        //newItem.transform.SetParent(ParentTransform.transform,false);
        Productxt.text = productname[i];
        Pricetxt.text = assetpriceurl[i].ToString();

            Instantiate(Mainprefab, ParentTransform);

    }


}
```

Below is the All products details API (Full API not shown)

```
"id":1,"product_name":"Dining Chair ","product_category_id":3
```

Below is the category API

```
[{"id":1,"category":"Chairs"},{"id":2,"category":"Tables"},{"id":3,"category":"Beds"}]
```

The "id" from the Category API is matched with the "product_category_id" from the Full products API to show them according to categories.

If I click chairs in the category view I want to show all the details of products which is having "product_category_id" =3 from already loaded details

//This below function is on different class

```
public void ButtonClickedOn(int buttonNo)
{
    buttonNo = Index;

    Debug.Log("Button clicked = " + buttonNo);

    if(buttonNo==0)
    {
 //Category 1 is clicked

    }

}
```

[image: Category view]

Comment: You can use Linq to organize your lists and data. It looks like you have all the list you want and you can easily compare "id" to "product_category_id".

Comment: How to show from already downloaded models.Should I save the details somewhere and later use it,like cache.

Comment: Yes. Make a dictionary which holds data for products against category.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize your `json` into `C# Object`. Then use `linq` to filter your list with a special category.

Here is a simple `console` working example

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class ProductDetails
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    public int product_category_id { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string productJson = @"[{'id': '1', 'product_name':'test', 'product_category_id': '1'},
                                {'id': '2', 'product_name':'Dining Chair', 'product_category_id': '3'},
                                {'id': '3', 'product_name':'Dining Chippsss', 'product_category_id': '3'}]";

        string categoryJson = @"[{ 'id':'1','category':'Chairs'},
                                { 'id':'2','category':'Tables'},
                                { 'id':'3','category':'Beds'}]";

        var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(categoryJson);
        var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductDetails>>(productJson);

        // Finding tables category
        var query = (from x in products
                     where x.product_category_id == 3
                     select x);

        foreach (var product in query)
        {
            var category = categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == product.product_category_id);

            Console.WriteLine("Product Name: " + product.product_name + 
                              " - Product Category: " + category.category);
        }
    }
}
```